# Margin specification on page

Tags: print-design, margin

When designing an A4 size flyer, do I have to put margins so as to know the printable areas of the A4 size page... If not, I wish to know if all areas of the A4 size page would be printable..

Comment: Depends entirely on what it's going to be printed on.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Printable areas depend on the printer. What kind of printer?  What printing process?

Comment: In the trivial sense, "NO" you do not have to put margins in the document, as the margins themselves are just guides for you to use and have no special meaning/use for Indesign. Compare with Bleed settings which do have meaning which you will notice in the export and print dialogs. However, it is wise to include them to remind yourself of the "safe area".

Comment: My biases have been exposed. I should have included the metric conversions and I do tend to think in terms of traditional print. 

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your images/colors/text within a safety area so they're not trimmed off. You can "bleed" color and images off the page if you want just by extending at least .125" beyond the trim area. Your safe area can be at least .125" to .25" - check with your printer what's best.

[image]

Comment: That's 3 mm and 3-6 mm in the rest of the world. 

Comment: Although this may work for offset printing, it won't work with many kinds of home/office printer, since many have an unprintable area around a sheet. The OP hasn't said what kind of printing/printer they are going to use - but does mention "printable areas". And so,  I suspect this is what they are referring to.

Comment: .. and one *can* ignore the safe area if desired... `:)`

Comment: @Scott, but wouldn't that be ... *unsafe*?

Comment: .. just means you're not unhappy if a bit of the internal copy gets mistakenly trimmed off.  (depends upon the overall design goal, of course.)